# Is it safe to migrate from JSON to JSONB in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In our DB we still use several fields typed as JSON. Is a conversion to JSONB always backward-compatible? My main concern is that we have several operations called in raw-SQL and I can't find in the documentation if all of them are supported for both JSON/JSONB.

Comment: If your code uses the various `json_XXX()` functions, it will fail as they don't accept `jsonb` - it has always bothered me, that those functions weren't overloaded so that one doesn't have to care about which exact json implementation is being used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hm, that's quite a deal-breaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether

- the order of keys matters for you;
- keys may be duplicated.

Only if one or both of these are true then - NO, otherwise yes.

Comment: are you sure about it? how about `json_XXX()` functions? (a question based on the comment I got above)

Comment: As far as I am aware all json functions and operators do have jsonb equivalents and not vice versa.

Comment: But you would have to rewrite those queries that have json_xxx to jsonb_xxx which may really be a deal-breaker.

Comment: seems to be a straightforward change, thanks